# Sorting files by name in Total Commander

Tags: total-commander

How can I enable sorting files by name in Total Commander by default? Is it possible?

Maybe some option / plugin?

I'm using Total Commander v8.0.

Answer (score 2):

In configuration window click "Display". You will find the **Sort method** there.

There is also "**Sorting directories**" where you should select "**as files**".

[image]

Source: http://beerpla.net/2008/10/11/how-to-sort-folders-the-same-way-as-files-in-total-commander/

Comment: Yes, bit it's enabling sorting only among the files with the same extension. Can i do it for all files?

Comment: try sorting method "Always by name"